# Java cast to List fails

Tags: java

I have a problem that I can't get my head round. I'm working some JSON data that's been converted to raw List and Map structures.  Then I'm testing whether a particular field is a List and if it is, I cast it to one in order to work with it further.

So I have;

```
if (value != null && value instanceof List){
   List listValue = (List) value;
   ...
}
```

In the Eclipse debugger, I can clearly see that value is an ArrayList, and it contains a Map, and so the code continues to the next line where the cast occurs.  The result of the cast is an empty List - that is, listValue is a List with nothing in it.  I don't understand why this should be the case.  Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

**Update:** It does seem it was a concurrency problem.  I've posted an answer, to which comments are welcome.  Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: The code you have here won't do anything to the contents of the  list - it'll behave as you expect. If your list is being emptied, then there's something else going on!

Comment: Hence my confusion...

Comment: are you sure you have values in `value`?   -  just checking

Comment: You say this is JSON. What JSON library do you use?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the list actually has any items in it?

Comment: you can see the contents of the list through the debugger.

Comment: @NimChimpsky, no, it's just an Object before I check type.  It repeatably has a HashMap<String,String> inside before the cast occurs

Comment: can you post the image of your Eclipse inspect object view? we can try to debug

Comment: As mentioned in one of the other answers, I suspect a concurrency problem - I'll review the code and post my findings

Comment: I disagree - I think it could still be a list, but the list could be emptied by some other code.  Not that it should, of course.  If that's happening, then there is a bug in my code.

Comment: @MickSear If you print out the size directly before and the cast (within the if statement) and directly before the if statement, what do you get? If it changes in that case, it can only be a concurrency issue as far as I can see.

Comment: @NimChimpsky It's a list alright, but how do you imagine he will use it as a list without downcasting?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to have been a concurrency problem.  Posting here helped me reach that conclusion.  My own fault for passing a mutable object into an @Async method and then not expecting it to change.  Once I sorted that little issue out, my problem went away, as expected.